# How to override global yarn registry for particular project

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

For most projects I pull packages from the internal server, so it's been added by

`yarn config set registry http://custom-packages-server.com`

But now in the new project I'd like to use the different (default) one, but use it in that particular project only. As far as I understood if I run the following command inside of new project's directory

`yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com`

it's going to update global registry value for all other projects as well, so they also will be looking for packages in the new place.

So is there a possibility in yarn to override global registry record for a specific project only?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the way how to achieve that.

It turned out that you can use [.yarnrc](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/) file inside the project's directory (yeah, pretty much the same like `.npmrc`). And there you can specify custom config properties which yarn will look into first.

So that's how my .yarnrc file looks now.

```
registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com"
```

Comment: But would this disable all rules in the global `.yarnrc` or will it just override them?

Comment: They get merged as the tree is traversed upwards (_.yarnrc files allow you to configure additional Yarn features. The config command may also be used to set these options. Yarn will merge .yarnrc files up the file tree._)  https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/ - You can see the resolution order by running a command with the `--verbose` flag (e.g. `yarn upgrade react --verbose`)

Comment: To specifically answer @paul, the earlier files take precedence.

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to temporarily override the registry for one `yarn` command, without having to modify a file:

```
yarn --registry=https://registry.company.com/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
npm config delete registry
```

you can delete old yarnrc

Comment: This was so very helpful, thank you! The other answers did not work for me