# Use custom registy, ideally from package.json

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-config

In my `package.json` I have

```
"config": {
  "registry": "https://registry.example.net"
}
```

In order to use a local registry. If I execute `yarn install --verbose` though, I see yarn does not use this but uses its own registry:

```
Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ts-node/-/ts-node-8.3.0.tgz".
```

I managed to set the yarn registry manually

```
yarn config set registry https://registry.example.net
```

Even then, in verbose mode, it shows me that it is sending GET requests to `registry.yarnpkg.com`.

Also I need this to be configured so it also uses this registry on other dev machines and jenkins.

How can I get yarn to use my custom registry, ideally from a config file?

Comment: Perhaps consider adding a `.yarnrc` file inside your project's directory (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998418/how-to-override-global-yarn-registry-for-particular-project#answer-46000761)) instead of defining the registry it in _package.json_.

Comment: @RobC Good idea, but it didn't work for me. I added both .npmrc and .yarnrc with registry and repository pointing to my nexus mirror, but the output shows it is still using `registry.yarnpkg.com` :-(

Comment: There is also this closed issue [#606](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/606), Perhaps try some of the suggestions mentioned there, such as adding a trailing single (or double) slash to the registry URL, i.e. `https://.../` or `https://...//` - I suppose it's worth trying.